# No server appears when I try to login to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to login to SQL Management Studio and try to pick a Server, no server appears in the list. What could be wrong?

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

I tried and got this:

[image]

Comment: You haven't installed a local instance?

Comment: How do I find out whether I installed local instance or not?

Comment: Did you see the screen shown in the first screenshot from [this blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/eric_johnson/archive/2008/07/10/new-sql-server-2008-install-contains-some-useful-features.aspx) when you installed?

Comment: Yes I did see. I choose the first option

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you start the SQL Server service, where it is installed
2. Give machine name or IP in server name
3. If it is SQL Express, you need to do machine-name\SQLEXPRESS

Answer (score 0):

try to write "localhost" in server name . then press connect if it give any error then go to configuration manager and check whether sql server instance running or not .

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install (and make sure its running), the SQL Server Browser service.

> > ..your named instances will not be published in the list of SQL Server instances on the network (which could be a good thing), if the service is not running.

More here: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1946/overview-of-the-sql-server-browser-service/